# Why does the reflexive pronoun change in this case when the subject is moved from the first position to the third position?

Tags: pronoun, reflexive

I recently came across this sentence:

> Dann machen sich meine Familie und ich auf den Weg nach Italien.

Initially, I thought the "sich" was a mistake and it should be "uns" but a native speaker told me this sentence is grammatically correct. However, if we move the subjects so it is at the beginning:

> Meine Familie und ich machen uns dann auf den Weg nach Italien.

Then the reflexive pronoun is indeed "uns" and I was told this is also correct. Can someone explain to me what is going on - namely why is the reflexive pronoun not always "uns" - and if there is a name for this phenomenon?

Also, I imagine that the order of subjects is irrelevant so the following sentences are correct? (I am aware it can be impolite and/or sound strange to put "ich" first):

> Dann machen sich ich und meine Familie auf den Weg nach Italien.
>
> Ich und meine Familie machen uns dann auf den Weg nach Italien.

Comment: second quote "and" -> "und"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reflexive pronoun is both declined **and** follows the verb conjugation.

```
           Singular                             Plural
           1.      2.      3.                   1.     2.     3
Nominativ  ----    ----    ----                 ----   ----   ----
Genitiv    meiner  deiner  seiner/ihrer/seiner  unser  eurer  ihrer
Dativ      mir     dir     sich                 uns    euch   sich
Akkusativ  mich    dich    sich                 uns    euch   sich
```

The genitive is very seldom used, even in educated speech. It's usually replaced by dative. Nominative makes no sense at all.

> Ihr gedenkt **eurer**. *(Genitiv)*
>
> Sie macht **sich** Essen. *(Dativ)*
>
> Wir hören **uns**. *(Akkusativ)*

Your examples differ in the person. In the first example, you are talking about yourself and your family in third person plural:

> Dann machen sich **meine Familie und ich** auf den Weg nach Italien.
>
> Dann machen **sie** sich auf den auf den Weg nach Italien.
>
> Meine Familie **u**nd ich machen sich dann auf den Weg nach Italien.

While the other you are talking in first person plural:

> Meine Familie **u**nd ich machen uns dann auf den Weg nach Italien.
>
> **Wir** machen uns dann auf den Weg nach Italien.

---

And sure, the order of subjects is irrelevant for grammar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand why the person of the first sentence should differ from the second sentence. All that differs (in my eyes) between the sentences is the position of the nominative and moving it shouldn't change the person, should it? I also feel that by saying it is equivalent to "sie" removes the implication that I am included in the person, i.e. "sie" could be "meine Familie und Freundin", while with "wir" it is clear that "ich" is always included with whoever else.

Comment: The difference lies in *sich* vs. *uns* entirely. *Sich* is a marker for third person, while *uns* is a marker for first person. And no, my sentence with *sie* also includes you. Because it's an outside view now, without your notion of *meine* and *ich*.

Comment: I've added another example for the sentence with *sich* which follows exactly the pattern of your sentence with *uns*.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification, it's more clear to me now. It's not something I would have expected.

Comment: Is "Dann machen wir uns auf den Weg nach Italien" not a valid rephrasal?

Comment: Sure it is. Why?

Comment: Because then it seems to me it would also be acceptable "Dann machen uns meine Familie und ich auf den Weg nach Italien" Would it not?

Comment: That's not the common word order. It's *machen wir uns*, not *machen uns wir*. But as soon you have a list of subjects, the third person view is more common. Sorry, not everything in languages fits into rules.

Comment: Ahh, THAT'S IT! The key is the list of subjects, thanks Janka.